# Cannot differentiate JWT token expiration error & Istio RBAC access denied error

Tags: istio

I've installed istio v1.1.1 and I have trouble using Istio Authentication Policy. i.e. Most of my micro-services need to support end-user authentication(JWT token) & service-service authentication(via istio mTLS) at the same time.
I've designed my Istio authentication Policy with both mTLS & JWT authentication on. I have to set **originIsOptional** to **true**, because service-service call only has K8S ServiceAccount as service identity.

Now, the problem is: if the JWT token expires or is missing, istio will return 403-RBAC acccess denied because JWT authentication will be by-passed & RBAC will take effect.
If I set **originIsOptional** to **false**. JWT expiration/missing will return 401-JWT token failure as expected, but service-service call will be blocked as JWT token is mandatory.

```
apiVersion: "authentication.istio.io/v1alpha1"
kind: "Policy"
metadata:
  name: "default"
  namespace: "ns-fota"
spec:
  peers:
 1. mtls: {}
  origins:
 2. jwt:
      issuer: "https://47.100.178.136:9444/oauth2/token"
      jwksUri: "http://47.100.178.136:9764/oauth2/jwks"
  principalBinding: USE_ORIGIN
  originIsOptional: true
EOF
```

My questions:

1. Why service-service call(no JWT token, only K8S ServiceAccount/Istio mTLS) passes in the attached configuration? **principalBinding** is configured **USE_ORIGIN**. Does it mean that only JWT user principal is valid?
2. How to support both jwt/mTLS authentication, meanwhile the system can differentiate the jwt token missing & Istio RBAC failure?

Comment: to make it more clear: in the above configuration, jwt token expiration/missing will return RBAC access denied(HTTP 403 error), but actually it's not real RBAC access issue, it should be jwt token validation error(HTTP 401). I cannot differentiate the jwt expiration & RBAC access error.

Comment: Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: not yet, but we've worked around it. we set policy for istio-ingress saying JWT is required which means it'll correctly return 401/403. At the same time, we set policy for my app domain 'ns-fota' saying that JWT token is optional which allows ServiceAccount to take place. It's not perfect since JWT valiation is done twice but it's still acceptable.

Comment: Thanks for the details. It would be great if you put your solution as an answer for the future community reference.